# Child Views ( Pressable, TouchableOpacity etc.) are not responding to touch events if wrapped inside a Custom Native Android View

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-native-ui-component

I have 2 custom native android view's ( the first custom view extends from RelativeLayout while the 2nd one extends from ReactViewGroup ) which wraps normal react-native components like TouchableOpacity, Pressable etc. I am passing onPress listeners to these but none of them are getting fired. I have tried overriding the onTouchEvent of my custom native android view but they are never called so I am thinking the touch event is consumed by one of the child views  but still it fails to call the onPress listeners for the same.

Is there a way to effectively debug this ? A way for me to go down the touch event hierarchy and see who all gets the touch event ?

I have tried placing a breakpoint on the dispatchTouchEvent by overriding in the custom native android view and it gets called as well but I cant seem to effectively debug it due to a long chain of calls that it makes.